# MATLAB programming question dealing with image manipulation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Question: Request edge to be cropped (1. top, 2. left, 3. right, 4. bottom), and number of pixels to remove and does it.
Implement as a function: pic_new = crop_image(pic,direction,pixels);

How do I go about making a function with the indicated inputs? I know there is a function called imcrop() but I can't seem to get it to work. Please help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

But `imcrop` is the exact function you need to use. In your case, it should be like this:

First, construct a rectangle by coordinates and it's height and width:

```
x = 50 
y = 50
height = 20
width = 20
```

Then, load and crop the image:

```
I = imread('image.png');
I2 = imcrop(I, [x, y, height, width]);
imshow(I), figure, imshow(I2)
```

Comment: what about the number of pixels to remove? I need to write a function with 3 inputs: picName, direction and pixels. I need to ask for the direction and the number of pixels to remove

Comment: Well, imagine you have a 100x100 picture, and need to crop 10 pixels from left side. Then the "cropping" rectangle is x=10, y=0, height=100, width=90.

Comment: I see, thank you! But how would the "cropping" rectangle differ for 10 pixels cropped from the right side? Would it be -10?

Comment: Yep, if by -10 you mean x = 0 (!), y=0 height=100 width=90

Comment: Hmmm. How would I do this without using the imcrop() function? I am not allowed to use any complex,built-in image manipulation functions such as imcrop()

Answer (score 0):

You begin a function definition like this:

```
function [out1, out2] = my_func(in1, in2, in3)
```

You can handle a range of behaviours based on the value of variable like this:

```
switch (x)
    case 1
        % Stuff for x==1
    case 2
        % Stuff for x==2
    case 3
        % Stuff for x==3
    otherwise
        % Stuff for all other values of x
end
```

You can remove elements from an array like this:

```
matrix_out = matrix_in(x1:x2, y1:y2, :);
```

(Remember that an image is usually represented as a 2D array (or 3D if it's RGB).

This should be enough to answer your question.  If it's not, you need to be more clear about what you want to do.